# Show Nav when scroll up but hide on scroll down when a notification bar in the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to code a sticky nav with perfect smooth show-hide animation.
But the problem is I have a notification bar on the top of the nav. So it should show when scrolling up finished but hide when scrolling down.

Here is what I am Cdading: https://codepen.io/exclutips/pen/wvEYRBe

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        
        el_autohide = document.querySelector('.autohide');
        
        // add padding-top to bady (if necessary)
        navbar_height = document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight;
    notification_height = document.querySelector('.notification-banner').offsetHeight;
        el_autohide.style.marginTop = notification_height + 'px';

        if(el_autohide){
            
            var last_scroll_top = 0;
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
                let scroll_top = window.scrollY;
               if(scroll_top < last_scroll_top) {
                    el_autohide.classList.remove('scrolled-down');
                    el_autohide.classList.add('scrolled-up');
                }
                else {
                    el_autohide.classList.remove('scrolled-up');
                    el_autohide.classList.add('scrolled-down');
                }
                last_scroll_top = scroll_top;

            }); 
            // window.addEventListener

        }
        // if
        
    }); 
    // DOMContentLoaded  end
```

```css
.autohide{
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1030;
}

.scrolled-down{
        transform:translateY(-100%); transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.scrolled-up{
        transform:translateY(0); transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.notification-banner{
  background:yellow;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:14px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="keywords" content="htmlcss bootstrap menu, scroll detect, show on scrolling page, navbar, menu CSS examples" />
<meta name="description" content="Auto hide navbar or header on scroll down. Page examples, Bootstrap 5" />  

<title>Navbar hide on scroll down, show on scroll up. Code example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="notification-banner">My Custom notification</div>
<!-- ============= COMPONENT ============== -->
<nav class="autohide navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main_nav"  aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Menu item </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Menu item </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown right </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Submenu item 1</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Submenu item 2 </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

  </div> <!-- navbar-collapse.// -->
 </div> <!-- container-fluid.// -->
</nav>
<!-- ============= COMPONENT END// ============== -->



<div class="container" style="max-width: 720px">

<header class="py-4">
    <h2>Demo page </h2> 
</header> <!-- section-header.// -->

<section>

        
        <h6>Demo for hide navbar on scroll down, show on scroll up, <br> Based on Bootstrap 5 CSS framework.  </h6>
        <p>For this demo page you should connect to the internet to receive files from CDN  like Bootstrap5 CSS, Bootstrap5 JS</p>

        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusm dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusm od
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            
        </p>
        <a href="http://bootstrap-menu.com/detail-autohide.html" class="btn btn-success"> &laquo; Back to tutorial or Download code</a>
        <br><br><br><br>
</section>


</div><!-- container //  -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using position:sticky for the .scrolled-up class like this:

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        
        el_autohide = document.querySelector('.autohide');
        
        // add padding-top to bady (if necessary)
        navbar_height = document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight;
    notification_height = document.querySelector('.notification-banner').offsetHeight;
        el_autohide.style.marginTop = notification_height + 'px';

        if(el_autohide){
            
            var last_scroll_top = 0;
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
                let scroll_top = window.scrollY;
               if(scroll_top < last_scroll_top) {
                    el_autohide.classList.remove('scrolled-down');
                    el_autohide.classList.add('scrolled-up');
                }
                else {
                    el_autohide.classList.remove('scrolled-up');
                    el_autohide.classList.add('scrolled-down');
                }
                last_scroll_top = scroll_top;

            }); 
            // window.addEventListener

        }
        // if
        
    }); 
    // DOMContentLoaded  end
```

```css
.autohide{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1030;
}

.scrolled-down{
    transform:translateY(-100%);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;            
}

.scrolled-up{
    transform:translateY(0);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
#mynavbar{
    position: sticky !important;
}

.notification-banner{
  background:yellow;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:14px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="keywords" content="htmlcss bootstrap menu, scroll detect, show on scrolling page, navbar, menu CSS examples" />
<meta name="description" content="Auto hide navbar or header on scroll down. Page examples, Bootstrap 5" />  

<title>Navbar hide on scroll down, show on scroll up. Code example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="notification-banner">My Custom notification</div>
<!-- ============= COMPONENT ============== -->
<nav id="mynavbar" class="autohide navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main_nav"  aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Menu item </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Menu item </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown right </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Submenu item 1</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Submenu item 2 </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

  </div> <!-- navbar-collapse.// -->
 </div> <!-- container-fluid.// -->
</nav>
<!-- ============= COMPONENT END// ============== -->



<div class="container" style="max-width: 720px">

<header class="py-4">
    <h2>Demo page </h2> 
</header> <!-- section-header.// -->

<section>

        
        <h6>Demo for hide navbar on scroll down, show on scroll up, <br> Based on Bootstrap 5 CSS framework.  </h6>
        <p>For this demo page you should connect to the internet to receive files from CDN  like Bootstrap5 CSS, Bootstrap5 JS</p>

        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusm dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusm od
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            
        </p>
        <a href="http://bootstrap-menu.com/detail-autohide.html" class="btn btn-success"> &laquo; Back to tutorial or Download code</a>
        <br><br><br><br>
</section>


</div><!-- container //  -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No bro I mean show the menu when scrolling up but hide on scrolling down.